# Comparar elementos de un arreglo en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Me gustaría saber como comparar las filas de una matriz. Esto es con el fin de verificar si las filas todos los elementos de la fila son multiplos de si mismos. Me queda claro que un numero es multiplo de otro cuando el resultado de su modulo es 0. Ahora, mi problema es que digamos que yo tengo esta matriz

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces digamos que yo quiero comparar la primera fila que tiene los numeros 4 y 8, obviamente son múltiplos, al igual que la segunda.

Alguna idea por favor?

Gracias!

Comment: Agrega una breve descripción de lo que has buscado/investigado. Ref. [ask].

Answer (score 1):

La forma mas facil es crear dos iteraciones (for) que te den las combinaciones de dos filas a comparar...

Una vez que tengas las dos filas entonces necesitas otro for para compara los elementos y que vaya moviendo en cada una de las posiciones a fin de probar `e1 % e%2 == 0`

Answer (score 1):

Seria algo asi:
`var miArray = [[4,5],[8,10]];

for(i=0; i<miArray.length; i++){
    if((miArray[i][1]%miArray[i][0])==0){
        alert(miArray[i][1]+" es muñtiplo de "+miArray[i][0]);
    } else {
        alert(miArray[i][1]+" no es muñtiplo de "+miArray[i][0]);
    }
}`